# Code restructuring and Base Page

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

I have a Windows Phone 7.5/Silverlight app.

I have some code that I duplicate in some sense on most of my pages.
e.g. of Code duplication:

1: OnNavigatedTo - I Stop animations, clear BackStack, add event handlers(same ones on each page), etc.

2: OnNaviateFrom - I Stop animations and set them to null, remove event handlers, stop all sounds, dispose soundffects and instances,etc.

3: OnInitilalizeComponent - I set up my SoundEffects

4: On image click I play SoundEffects

So what would be the best way so I don't have to replicate the code in all pages?

I was thinking of somekind of base class or page?

Any ideas really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing the same thing in each page then a base Page class makes perfect sense.

```
public class MyPhoneApplicationPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MyPhoneApplicationPage()
    {
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        // Do Stuff
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        // Do Stuff
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        //set up my SoundEffects
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. That's exactly on my mind. I wanted to gather ideas and pros/cons before I start moving my code here and there.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot you're gonna want to detach that Loaded event! just Attach & Detach it in OnNavigatedTo/From

Comment: Thanks. I have started working on the basepage way- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2011/03/03/creating-a-custom-base-page-for-windows-phone-7.aspx